# Row select/deselect only by clicking checkbox - Jquery Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am creating a jquery datatable as below

```
 var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  'ajax': 'https://gyrocode.github.io/files/jquery-datatables/arrays_id.json',
  'columnDefs': [
     {
        'targets': 0,
        'checkboxes': {
           'selectRow': true
        }
     }
  ],
  'select': {
     'style': 'multi'
  },
  'order': [[1, 'asc']]
   });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4ovbtwgd/1/

But i have a requirement where i want to select/deselect row only based on checkbox click.Now the row will get selected if we click any of the column in a row.But based on requirement,the row should be selected/deselect based on checkbox click only.Can anyone help on this with a sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `selector` inside `select option` like [documentaion says](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox.html):

```
select: {
  style:    'multi',
  selector: 'td:first-child'
},
```

Comment: Thanks..i will check